# Indexing through an array by column number

Tags: vba, columnsorting

I've looked up info with regards to column attributes.  I'm trying to perform some insertions and copying of information within an array. The crux of my issue is that I want o nest some actions within a loop, so I need to index the column by a number not letter.

The first thing I do is find a starting point based upon a header name:

```
Dim EnvCondCol As String
Dim EnvCondColN As Long
Dim lColVVS As Integer
lColVVS = VET_VS.UsedRange.Columns.Count ' finds last column
For n = 1 To lColVVS
    If UCase(VET_VS.Cells(3, n).Value) Like "*ENVIRONMENTAL CONDITION*" Then ' All Caps when using "like"
        EnvCondCol = Split(VET_VS.Cells(3, n).Address, "$")(1)
        EnvCondColN = Range(EnvCondCol & 1).Column
        Exit For
    End If
Next n
```

This works and when I watch EnvCondCol and EnvCondColN is can see EnvCondCol = "I" and EnvCondColN = "9"
Eventually, I want to insert a new column, and this line generates a syntax error:

```
VET_VS.Range(Columns.(EnvCondColN)).EntireColumn.Insert
```

When I watch EnvCondColN, it is a number, and I have tried changing the dim to other types, such as integer

Also elsewhere, I want to copy information from a cell into another cell from within a loop. This generates a syntax error.

```
VET_VS.Range(Columns.(EnvCondColN + i)).Copy VET_VS.Range(Columns.(EnvCondColN + j))
```

If I replace EnvCondColN with a value like 5, then this works.  Example: `VET_VS.Range(Columns.(5)).EntireColumn.Insert`

Why isn't the variable working as a column reference??

Thank you all for looking!

Comment: try `VET_VS.Columns(EnvCondColN).EntireColumn.Insert`

Comment: try `Range(EnvCondCol & 1).EntireColumn.Insert`

Comment: HTH that change worked.  I am perplexed because I have used the Sheet.range(x).copy sheet.range(y) approach  with success before except x and y were references using column letters such as C:C or C2 etc ... Why does the range no longer work?

Comment: FaneDuru - your answer involved using column letters, so it was what I was trying to avoid.  One cannot use F+1 without getting an error.

Comment: HTH - I don't see the check box to mark your answer as good.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @Barnapkin, added answer

Comment: @Barnapkin, `Sheet.range(x)` works if `x` is a valid range argument, so it's up to what you actually used. But your `VET_VS.Range(Columns.(EnvCondColN + i))` had an invalid range argument

Comment: HTH thank you for the follow up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
 VET_VS.Range(Columns.(EnvCondColN)).EntireColumn.Insert
```

to

```
 VET_VS.Columns(EnvCondColN).EntireColumn.Insert
```